# java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: _ebean_props always occur when upgrade Ebean from 3.3.4 to 4.5.5,

Tags: java, scala, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.3

I upgraded Ebean  from 3.3.4 to 4.5.5，but the following error is always occur:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: _ebean_props
```

and it still existed after i run "activator clean, compile" command.

I run "activator ui" command,I saw the following logs:

```
**Read from stdout: Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
Read from stdout:   * org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm:3.3.4 -> 4.5.5
    * org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm:3.3.4 -> 4.5.5
Read from stdout:   * org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm-agent:3.2.2 -> 4.5.2
    * org.avaje.ebeanorm:avaje-ebeanorm-agent:3.2.2 -> 4.5.2
Read from stdout: Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings**
```

My play framework is 2.3.8, Scala SDK is 2.11.6.

How to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Play Framework 2.3 and lower will work with the latest versions (4.x) of Ebean yet.  In Play 2.4, they are decoupling the play-ebean plugin which will hopefully pave the way to allow for using a newer version of Ebean.

You can watch this thread for updated information:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2926

Also, the Play-Ebean plugin that'll get used in Play 2.4:
https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean

Comment: Thanks very much, Play 2.4 has not been release, and also It  need the developer  to build Play-Ebean for his project.  It has a big risk if use Play 2.4 and Play-Ebean in production environment. right?

Comment: I would agree that there is definitely a risk to using the pre-release version of Play 2.4 right now.  We have just been using Play 2.3.8 still which has a 3.x version of ebean which works alright for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing this.  You have to not include `javaEbean` in your sbt includes, and instead include the new ebean libraries. (eg: `"org.avaje.ebeanorm" % "avaje-ebeanorm" % "4.5.5"`).  You will also need to enable enhancement on your own either via the java agent or agent loader (see: [Ebean ORM::Enhancement](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs#enhancement))

Note, you will also need to change the include statements in your model, services, etc classes to point to the new packages (they changed i think from 3.x to 4.x), it will be obvious when you compile if your IDE doesn't warn you.

Comment: Thanks, Christien, I'll try to do as you said.